# Start 2 Python Scripts on server start/restart?

Tags: linux, debian

that when my Debian10 Root Server starts or restarts, that two python scripts are starting:

`python3.9 ./NarcoCity/main.py` and
`python3.9 ./NCVerification/main.py`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You start them the same way you run any other program when the server starts. If you don't know how to do that, it's a question for [unix.se].

Comment: i want to start it automaticly

Comment: I understood that. Like I said, you do it the same way as you start anything else automatically at boot time. If you're the server system administrator, you should know how to do this. If you're not the sysadmin, you should ask them to configure it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a systemd script, here you can find more info http://tuxgraphics.org/npa/systemd-scripts/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).